# When using width:100vw in nuxt.js there is extra white space

Tags: html, css

I'm building component banner in my nuxt.js.

I tried a lot of way to solved this problem but it still not solved yet, i tried to add `margin:0;` and `padding:0;` in my `html` and `body` tag but the white space is still there. I tried another solution in this topic about [using-100vw-and-vh-creates-extra-space-beyond-viewport-size-how-do-i-get-rid-of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25320289/using-100vw-and-vh-creates-extra-space-beyond-viewport-size-how-do-i-get-rid-of) but when I try it the result is still the same. I try this topic too about [100vw-causing-horizontal-overflow-but-only-if-more-than-one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367345/100vw-causing-horizontal-overflow-but-only-if-more-than-one) but there is no luck.

this is my banner component:

```
<template>
  <div id="paham-banner-career">
    <div class="banner-container">
      <h2>Let's See Where You Fit In</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

this is my css:

```
<style lang="css" scoped>
#paham-banner-career{
    font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
    background-color: #3b73c5;
    width: 100vw;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#paham-banner-career .banner-container{
    margin: 100px auto;
    padding: 25px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 1200px;
}

#paham-banner-career h2{
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
```

can someone save me to solve this?

this is what I got right now [image: there is extra white space that I mark]

Answer (score 0):

try adding `box-sizing`

```
<style lang="css" scoped>

*{box-sizing: border-box;}

#paham-banner-career{
    font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
    background-color: #3b73c5;
    width: 100vw;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#paham-banner-career .banner-container{
    margin: 100px auto;
    padding: 25px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 1200px;
}

#paham-banner-career h2{
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thankyou for the response, where I must add it? when I try it there is nothing change

Comment: i have updated my answer add the entire line in your css and check.

Comment: I tried to add `box-sizing:border-box` like you did but still nothing happen

Comment: can you please create the snippet with the same behavior so i can check.

Comment: I add a my component in this fiddle but it is already work but not in my full code https://jsfiddle.net/RFTaurus/qx0ozLw1/

Comment: this means there something else in your code which have issue. you  must have to produce that issue in jsfiddle then and only then we will be able to help you.